# Appending a col div with jQuery in a for loop only gives me results on the first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, ajax

I am retrieving an AJAX dump from a Django python Function. 
Then, I am trying to reflect the data on a bootstrap row + column table.
However, when using append() in an array list, I only seem to get the first row of the dump. When I remove the 2nd for loop, the dump works fine, just does not give me the rows of the months that I need.

I have more than one row worth of data, definitely.

What could be causing this?

//html code

```
<div id="category_filtered_list">
    <div class="row report_row mockup" id="category_mockup">
        <div class="col-md-1 name"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 code"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 forecasted"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 running_total"></div>
        <div class="monthsRows" id="monthsRows"></div>            

    </div>
</div>
```

```
//Ajax JS function
$.post(
                "",
                {
                    "getcategories": true,
                    'date-from': date_from,
                    'date-to': date_to
                },
                function(response) {
                    $("#category_filtered_list .report_row.product").remove()
                    data = JSON.parse(response);
                    for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                        obj = data[i]
                        var mockup = $('#category_mockup')
                        var temp_mockup = $(mockup).clone()
                        $("#category_filtered_list").append(temp_mockup)
                        $(mockup).attr('id',"temp_product");

                        var temp_prod = $("#temp_product")

                        $(temp_prod).find('.name').html(obj.category_name)
                        $(temp_prod).find('.code').html(obj.category_code)
                        $(temp_prod).find('.minor').html(obj.category_minor)
                        $(temp_prod).find('.parent').html(obj.category_parent)                        
                        $(temp_prod).find('.forecasted').html(obj.category_forecasted)
                        $(temp_prod).find('.running_total').html(obj.products_count)

//this for loop is causing the issue ******* when removed, the rest of the code works fine. Please note that obj.prods_num_per_month is an array

                    for (i=0; i<=obj.prods_num_per_month.length; i++){
                            $(temp_prod).find('.monthsRows').append(
                                $('<div class="col-xs-1">').html(obj.prods_num_per_month[i])

                            );
                        } 


                        $(temp_prod).removeClass('mockup');
                        $(temp_prod).addClass('product');
                        $(temp_prod).attr('id','')
                    }
                }
            ).done(function(){
                $("#filtering .message_loading").html("Completed! <i class='far fa-smile text-success'></i>")
                $("#filtering .message_loading").addClass("fading")
                $("#export_button").show()
                setTimeout(function(){ $("#filtering .message_loading").html('') }, 5000);
              });
```

I am expecting to get all rows with relevant data, but instead, I am just getting the first row.

Comment: Seemed you are missing `}` for this loop: `for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){`

Comment: Unfortunately, the for loop is closed, 2nd bracket before the done function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not my proudest moment... So.. The code works fine actually, but I have declared 'i' as the index for both 'for' loops, causing the main loop to terminate early..

I changed the index for the 2nd for loop and it's up and running as intended.

2 hours of debugging...Really not my proudest moment. Good news is it's fixed!